# determine the existence of positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: matrices, decidability, semidefinite-programming

Given a $d\times d$ complex matrix subspace $S$, we are asking whether there is some finite integer $n$ such that there exists a non-zero positive semi-definite matrix is orthogonal to $S^{\otimes n}$.

It is equivalent to ask whether there is some finite integer $n$ such that there exists a non-zero positive definite matrix lies in  $span\{[S^{+}]^{\otimes n}\cup S^{\otimes n}\}$, where $S^{+}$ denotes the complex conjugate matrix subspace.

Is this problem decidable?